# Python Pickle.load() not loading correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, pickle, google-api-client

```
SCOPES_SHEETS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
```

Gives read/write permissions ^

```
def main():
    service_sheets = get_google_service('sheets', 'v4', 'token_sheets.json', SCOPES_SHEETS)
    with open('services.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(service_sheets, f)
    with open('services.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        service_sheets = pickle.load(f)
    with open('serviceCopy.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(service_sheets, f)

def get_google_service(type, version, token, scope):
    store = file.Storage(token)
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', scope)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    return build(type, version, http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

I have a program that I want to run as a service in the background. It involves reading/writing things in a google sheet. For this I have to create a google service but I don't want to have to do it every time the code runs so I'm trying to store the service object in a file instead. For some reason the file `service.pkl` is different from `serviceCopy.pkl`. I've tried changing the encoding for `pickle.load(file, encoding='utf8')` but I keep getting files that don't match.

To my understanding they should be exactly the same.

I think the issue is with loading the saved file but I'm not sure what's causing it.

I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: I normally use  [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to read and write google spreadsheets.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito Thanks for the tip, I'll try this with gspread in a bit